# Where do I ask about the iOS Simulator?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where do I ask questions about a problem in the iOS Simulator? After I updated Xcode, the simulator gave me weird results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a development-related question about changes in code execution within the iOS Simulator, Stack Overflow would probably be the most appropriate place for this.

However, you need to make sure this is asked as a fully fleshed-out question that the community can answer. Stack Overflow is not the place to post bug reports with development tools, so if your only purpose is to post "I'm seeing this odd behavior, is anyone else?" I would not do so. If you're instead asking what might be wrong with your code, or how to work around a change in simulator behavior, that could be a good question. Actual bug reports should go to http://bugreport.apple.com, not here.

In your question, make sure to include all of the information needed to reproduce this behavior, including code, tool versions, the desired result, and what you're actually seeing. We need to be able to replicate your conditions without having your full codebase in order to even begin to help you.

If you can satisfy all of those conditions, you could ask about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure whether it's a bug. It's not code related. The problem only started after i updated Xcode.